# Random CORS requests failing if opCache is enabled on Laravel API side

Tags: php, laravel, axios, opcache

I have a standard Laravel 5.6 API with barryvdh/laravel-cors plugin to handle cors requests. If opCache is enabled I sometimes get random failed get requests to the Laravel API.

[image]

It is interesting that this happens only if there are more than 1 request at a time like in this case and if the headers of the request have been changed.

For the frontend I use Vue.js and axios and this is how I make the requests.

```
axios = require('axios');
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://api.aaa';
axios.defaults.timeout = 30000;
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+getToken(),
};

axios.get('api/pets')
     .then(response => {
            resolve(response);
     })
     .catch(error => {`enter code here`
            reject(error);
     });

axios.get('api/species')
     .then(response => {
            resolve(response);
     })
     .catch(error => {
            reject(error);
     });
```

I dont see anything wrong with the frontend and this only happens when opCache is enabled on the Laravel API`s side. Does somebody have a suggestion why this might happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried looking at the error logs for Laravel/PHP?

Comment: Of course - no errors in log files on failed requests(witch is roughly one out of five requests), but sometimes (on one out of 100 requests) I get also one of those 2 errors:No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified and Carbon dateTime method not found error wtich right now I am unable to reproduce... These errors I also get only if opCache is enabled.

Comment: This is the second error - I was able to reproduce it: Call to undefined method DateTime::getTimezone() in vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php. I should also say that this is fresh Laravel install and I have reinstalled and the problem is still occurring.